# Can I download folders from AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been using S3 to store a lot of backups. Parts of it work well. Data goes into S3 very nicely.

Getting data out is difficult. I can download files one at a time. However, I cannot find a way to download the *folders*. I can download individual files, but only 1 at a time.

Does anyone know how I can download folders from my S3 site?

Comment: Take a look at the examples here. https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples

Comment: i can only do it with cli sync,  aws s3 sync s3://bucket/ folder destination --exclude "*" --include ".txt" --profile your profile

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires you to install `aws-cli` locally and **configured** with your credentials, in order to solve your problem

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket /path/on/your/local/machine --recursive
```